# Build executable jar from multiple maven modules

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have problem with building the single executable jar from multiple maven modules.
So here is the situation: I have three maven modules: app -> persistence -> domain. I have parent pom.xml too. I added to this parent pom maven assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.toys.app.Service</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So when I type from command line in parent pom directory (which contain parent.pom and app, persistence and domain maven modules) command: **mvn assembly:assembly**
it gave my next error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building persistence 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) @ persistence ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ..................................... SUCCESS [3.147s]
[INFO] domain ............................................ SUCCESS [4.765s]
[INFO] persistence ....................................... FAILURE [0.570s]
[INFO] app ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.287s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 28 12:30:26 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project persistence: Failed to create assembly: Failed to resolve dependencies for project: com.toys:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) com.toys:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.toys -DartifactId=domain -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.toys -DartifactId=domain -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) com.toys:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2) com.toys:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR] com.toys:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :persistence
```

Every other maven life-cycles works fine! Can Anyone help me?

Comment: What's the scope of those dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add execution phase:

```
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.toys.app.Service</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>               
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                  
          </configuration>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: It's work, but when I extract this jar, there are no packages and classes what I wrote!

Comment: How do you run this build ? First: try to run 'install' on each submodule. then run 'package' goal on desired module.

Comment: I tried to run "install" on each module, the domain module done success, but the persistence module which are depend on domain module gave me an error: **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project persistence: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.toys:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.toys:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), ...]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.toys:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.toys:parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]**

Comment: And what is result of 'install' of whole project ?
Also check your maven central repository settings. It could be that default maven repository is switched off...

Comment: "Install" of whole project done successfully. I have downloaded all this dependencies in my maven local repository. When I remove it from there and run "compile", the dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: thats good. What about your jar in the target folder - it's still doesnt contain your classes ?

Comment: Ok, I tried run "clean" phase and after that "package" phase. Now all of my modules (app, persistence and domain) contains target dir with builded jar module. But on the top level, there is no jar with dependencies and those modules.

Comment: Which level? you mean parent target folder ? Also may be it's better to go to chat :)

Comment: I solve this prombelm. I my child pom was missing next code:

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Comment: I try to do the same thing but it builds up an empty jar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068692/how-to-create-jar-from-submodules-of-module

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add project 'distribution' on the same level as your app, persistence, domain projects.

```
<project>

  <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
    ...
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>app</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.toys.app.Service</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>               
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                  
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        <plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I had similar problems when trying to create distribution in the reactor POM, after moving to its own project - no headaches.

Also, don't forget to add 'distribution' module to the reactor project.