# How to create Jar from submodules of module?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I have this java maven project structure

```
- parentModule
    - firstChildModule
    - firstChildModule
    - firstChildModule
        - secondChildModule -> **jar**
            - thirdChildModule
            - thirdChildModule
            - thirdChildModule
```

And I want to package the secondChildModule module as a jar containing its submodules.

I have tried to set the packaging type to pom but an exception is thrown stating that 'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid.

So my question is how to do this the right way?
I mention that only the thirdChildModule module types will contain source code.

here are the sources for firstChildModule, secondChildModule and

firstChildModule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstChildModule</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>secondChildModule</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

secondChildModule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>firstChildModule</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>secondChildModule</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Second Child Module</name>

    <modules>
        <module>thirdChildModule01</module>
        <module>thirdChildModule02</module>
        <module>thirdChildModule0</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

thirdChildModule

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>secondChildModule</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>thirdChildModule01</artifactId>

</project>
```

Comment: Just do `mvn clean package ` or `install` and you get your jars.

Comment: I want all those submodules compiled in one jar under its parent jar :)

Comment: Why would you want module jars be inside another jar, that's just a mess and loses the point of modular design, that's not a way to go.

Comment: the final jar will be executed in an engine, and in those 3 submodule is the code needed. It is well enough designed, anyway this is not in the question's scope

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you want jars within a jar or a single jar file that is the combined content of all child packages.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-assembly-plugin does what you need.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Set this plugin as follow in your secondchildmodule pom.xml file.

```
...
<artifactId>secondchildmodule</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Add this assembly descriptor to setup the output at src/main/assembly/assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.1.1 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.1.xsd">
<id>fat-jar</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <binaries />
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

The generated file at secondchildmodule/target

**jar -tf secondchildmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-jar.jar**

> META-INF/
> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
> thirdchildmodule1/
> thirdchildmodule1/Main.class
> thirdchildmodule2/
> thirdchildmodule2/Main.class
> thirdchildmodule3/
> thirdchildmodule3/Main.class
> thirdchildmodule3/another/
> thirdchildmodule3/another/pkg/
> thirdchildmodule3/another/pkg/AnotherClass.class